# Pass data between components React

Tags: reactjs

I'm new with React and I want to move an object data from one child component to another, this is my code:

```
import React from "react";
import SiteRow from "./SiteRow";
import AlertList from "../Alerts/AlertList";
import data from "../../static/fixtures/data.json";

const SiteList = () => {
    return (
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-8">
          <table className="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th scope="col">Site</th>
                <th scope="col">Alerts</th>
                <th scope="col">Savings</th>
                <th scope="col">Uptime</th>
                <th scope="col">Power</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <SiteRow sites={data.sites} />
          </table>
        </div>
        <AlertList />
      </div>
    );  
};

export default SiteList;
```

When I click in a row in the `SiteRow` component must show data in a child component `AlertRow` from `AlertList`, I've been looking for this but I'm stuck, any idea?

Thanks.

I was reading about React Context, but I don't got the idea for sharing the data.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do that,

1. one way is to create a state in the parent component of both
   children components.
2. The second way is to initialise React context.
3. Otherwise, there are external libraries such as redux for global
   sharing states.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to place the state in their common ancestor, in this case `SiteList`.

In `SiteRow` you create a callback prop (`onSelectSite` in the demo below) that will be called every time a row is clicked. In `SiteList` you will use that callback to update the state (`selectedSite` in the demo below). You will then pass such state to `AlertList`.

See working demo:

```js
const data = {sites: [{site: 'click me aaa'}, {site: 'click me bbb'}]};
const AlertList = ({ site }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <hr />
      AlertList - selected site: {JSON.stringify(site)}
    </div>
  );
}
const SiteRow = ({ sites, onSelectSite }) => {
  return (
    <tbody>
      {sites.map(s => <tr onClick={e => onSelectSite(s, e)}><td>{s.site}</td></tr>)}
    </tbody>
  );
}

const SiteList = () => {
    const [selectedSite, setSelectedSite] = React.useState(null);
    const handleSelectedSite = (site) => {
      setSelectedSite(site);
    }
    return (
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-8">
          <table className="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th scope="col">Site</th>
                <th scope="col">Alerts</th>
                <th scope="col">Savings</th>
                <th scope="col">Uptime</th>
                <th scope="col">Power</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <SiteRow sites={data.sites} onSelectSite={handleSelectedSite} />
          </table>
        </div>
        <AlertList site={selectedSite} />
      </div>
    );  
};

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('app')).render(<SiteList />);
```

```css
table, tr, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td { color: blue; cursor: pointer; }
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

If you have a very deep component tree. There are other ways to make this passing of props simpler, such as [Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) or libraries like Redux.